# Infinity in Delphi unit is translated to +INF in .hpp file

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I'm using C++Builder XE6 and wrote the following Delphi unit:

```pascal
unit JSONUtils;

interface

uses
  System.JSON, System.Math;

function GetJSONDouble (Value: TJSONValue; Path: string; Default: Double = Infinity): Double;

implementation

function GetJSONDouble (Value: TJSONValue; Path: string; Default: Double): Double;
begin
  Result := Value.GetValue<Double>(Path, Default);
end;

end.
```

When compiled, the following .hpp file is generated:

```cpp
// CodeGear C++Builder
// Copyright (c) 1995, 2014 by Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
// All rights reserved

// (DO NOT EDIT: machine generated header) 'JSONUtils.pas' rev: 27.00 (Windows)

#ifndef JsonutilsHPP
#define JsonutilsHPP

#pragma delphiheader begin
#pragma option push
#pragma option -w-      // All warnings off
#pragma option -Vx      // Zero-length empty class member 
#pragma pack(push,8)
#include <System.hpp>   // Pascal unit
#include <SysInit.hpp>  // Pascal unit
#include <System.JSON.hpp>  // Pascal unit
#include <System.Math.hpp>  // Pascal unit

//-- user supplied -----------------------------------------------------------

namespace Jsonutils
{
//-- type declarations -------------------------------------------------------
//-- var, const, procedure ---------------------------------------------------
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE double __fastcall GetJSONDouble(System::Json::TJSONValue* Value, System::UnicodeString Path, double Default = +INF);
}   /* namespace Jsonutils */
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_JSONUTILS)
using namespace Jsonutils;
#endif
#pragma pack(pop)
#pragma option pop

#pragma delphiheader end.
//-- end unit ----------------------------------------------------------------
#endif  // JsonutilsHPP
```

Note that the default value of `Infinity` in the `.pas` file is translated to `+INF` in the `.hpp` file.

When I include the `.hpp` file in a C++ unit, I get the following compiler error:

```
[bcc32 Error] JSONUtils.hpp(26): E2451 Undefined symbol 'INF'
```

Understandable, because `INF` is not defined in `System.Math.hpp`, but `Infinity` is.

How do I get the compiler to output `Infinity` (or `HUGE_VAL`) to the `.hpp` file instead of `+INF`?

Comment: @David If I write `double X = Infinity, Y = HUGE_VAL;`, the comparison `(X == Y)` evaluates to `true`. Both X and Y contain the value `0x7FF0000000000000`.

Comment: Oh, I guess I'm wrong then, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get the compiler to output `Infinity` (or `HUGE_VAL`) to the `.hpp` file instead of `+INF`?

AFAIK, you don't. That is simply how the Delphi compiler chose to translate `Infinity` for C++. Feel free to [submit a bug report to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com) about it.

In the meantime, as a workaround, what you could try instead is declaring `GetJSONDouble` with [`{$NODEFINE}`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/NODEFINE_directive_(Delphi)) or [`{$EXTERNALSYM}`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/External_Symbols_(Delphi)) to avoid the Delphi compiler from outputting a default declaration in the `.hpp`, and then use [`{$HPPEMIT}`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/HPP_emit_(Delphi)) to declare `GetJSONDouble()` yourself, eg:

```pascal
unit JSONUtils;

interface

uses
  System.JSON, System.Math;

{$EXTERNALSYM GetJSONDouble}
function GetJSONDouble (Value: TJSONValue; Path: string; Default: Double = Infinity): Double;

{$HPPEMIT OPENNAMESPACE}
{$HPPEMIT 'extern DELPHI_PACKAGE double __fastcall GetJSONDouble(System::Json::TJSONValue* Value, System::UnicodeString Path, double Default = System::Math::Infinity);'}
{$HPPEMIT CLOSENAMESPACE}

implementation

function GetJSONDouble (Value: TJSONValue; Path: string; Default: Double): Double;
begin
  Result := Value.GetValue<Double>(Path, Default);
end;

end.
```

Comment: That did the trick! I knew about `{$HPPEMIT '...'}`, but somehow missed `{$NODEFINE}` and `{$EXTERNALSYM ...}`. Thank you very much, Remy. I really appreciate your continuing effort.